# Should jQuery $.getJSON() method fail when the response is text/html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, content-type, getjson

Is it possible to force `$.getJSON()` function to raise an error when we try to get HTML with it (not `application/json`). It seems that this deferred just returns empty object to then (or done).

How can we find in `then` handler which `content-type` was processed in response?
I have the situation when server can return HTML instead of JSON when the service isn't available.

Comment: why don't you just throw an exception in the handler when the response is empty then?

Comment: It's quite simple actually, if the status is 20x and the response can successfully parsed by $.parseJSON, it is considered successful. It ignores the content-type because developers often forget to return it. You should test for null in .then and cause the promise to reject if it is null or empty string (or fix the server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.getJSON()` fails when the response is `text/html`. See this example:

```js
$.getJSON('http://httpbin.org/html')
  .then(() => console.log('success'), () => console.log('error'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, It definitely so, it seems that we use $.ajax somewhere without specifying correct content-type.